# AIR AS3 Android Sound plays once but never again after fade

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, audio, air

I have an AIR Android application which has multiple pages, each page has their own music and sound effects. Music is executed via code and the effects are part timeline and part code executed.

This all works fine on the AIR Simulator but as soon as I run it on a Tablet with Android 4.4.2 it is ok for the first page, but once the first page music and effects sound channels have been faded out (via a volume tween) you wont hear a sound from the application again. Android 4.2.2 however is fine.

I've traced the volumes and the values are fine, I've even tweened the SoundMixer volume itself and still not a sound.

The code is just basic soundmixer and soundtransform code, virtually identical to what is on adobe live docs. I've even skipped the first page and gone directly to the second to see if the sounds are working correctly and they are fine.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was: omni-4.4.2-20140128
Flashed version: omni-4.4.2-20140318
and all is fine in the world once again!